# (Laravel) Open modal dynamically with data from DB

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I'm pretty new in programming and I'm stuck with a problem which I really don't know how to solve.

Basically I have a view wich contains a table filled with events:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('calendario/calendario_personale', 'CalendarioController@creaCalendarioPersonaleLista');

// controller
public function creaCalendarioPersonaleLista() {

    $lista_militi = Milite::where('Aktiv', '=', 'True')
        ->orderBy('Name')
        ->orderBy('Vorname')
        ->get();

    $milite = Milite::where('eMailB', '=', Auth::user()->email)
        ->first();

    $agenda = Milite::find($milite->KeyPerson)
        ->AgendaPersonale
        ->all();

    return View::make('calendario_personale', compact('agenda'))
        ->with('lista_militi', $lista_militi);

}

// view
<!-- ********** INIZIO EXTENDED MODAL - FORMULARIO ANNUNCIO ASSENZE ********** -->
<div id="annuncio_assenza" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="550">
@var $key = '4000';
@var $spec_agenda = Agenda::find($key)

<div class="modal-body">
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'CalendarioController@inviaAnnuncioAssenza']) }}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span class="_red"><h3> Annuncio d'assenza </h3>
            <h5> Da inviare almeno 48 ore prima dell'evento </h5></span>
            <br/>
            <h5> Non posso essere presente a <span class="_bold"> {{ $spec_agenda->Bezeichnung }} </span></h5>
            <h5> che si terr&agrave; il giorno <span class="_bold"> {{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($spec_agenda->Datum)) }} </span> alle ore <span class="_bold"> {{ date('H:i', strtotime($spec_agenda->Zeit)) }} </span></h5>
            <h5> per il seguente motivo: </h5><br/>
            <table id="form-assenza">
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ Form::checkbox('personale') }} Personale </td>
                    <td> {{ Form::checkbox('vacanza') }} Vacanza </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ Form::checkbox('professionale') }} Professionale </td>
                    <td> {{ Form::checkbox('militare') }} Servizio militare/PCi </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ Form::checkbox('infortunio') }} Infortunio/malattia </td>
                    <td> {{ Form::checkbox('altri_impegni') }} Altri impegni </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{ Form::hidden('cosa', $spec_agenda->Bezeichnung) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('data', date('d.m.Y', strtotime($spec_agenda->Datum))) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('ora', date('H:i', strtotime($spec_agenda->Zeit))) }}
            <br/><br/>
            <h5><span class="_red"> Da compilare in caso di assenza per Guardia Festiva, picchetto e/o appoggio: </span></h5>
            <h5> Verr&ograve; sostituita/o da: </h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" style="font-size: 1em" name="sostituto">
                    <option value=""> Seleziona un milite... </option>
                    @foreach($lista_militi as $militi)
                    <option value="{{ $militi->KeyPerson }}"> {{ $militi->Dienstgrad }} {{ $militi->Name }} {{ $militi->Vorname }} </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <br/><h5> Altro/Osservazioni </h5>
            <p> {{ Form::textarea('altro', null, ['class'=>'form-control _small', 'rows' => '3']) }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    {{ Form::button('Annulla', ['class'=>'btn btn-default', 'data-dismiss'=>'modal']) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Invia il formulario', ['class'=>'btn red']) }}
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
</div>    
<!-- ********** FINE EXTENDED MODAL - FORMULARIO ANNUNCIO ASSENZE ********** -->

<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- ********** INIZIO PORTLET ********** -->
    <div class="portlet box red profile margin-top-minus5">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Calendario personale
            </div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="calendario_personale"> Personale </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="calendario_corpo"> Corpo </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover _dark-grey" id="table_custom">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione su xs -->
                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg on-one-line"> Data </th>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione su sm, md e lg -->
                            <th class="hidden-xs on-one-line"> Data </th>
                            <th> Descrizione </th>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione sm, md e lg -->
                            <th class="hidden-xs on-one-line"> Assenza </th>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione xs -->
                            <th class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg on-one-line"> Ass. </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="link-disable">
                        @foreach($agenda as $evento)
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione su xs -->
                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg on-one-line">
                                <span class="_bold">
                                {{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($evento->Datum)) }}
                                </span><br/>
                                {{ $evento->dalle_alle }}
                            </td>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione su sm, md e lg -->
                            <td class="hidden-xs on-one-line">
                                <span class="_bold">
                                {{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($evento->Datum)) }}
                                </span> &nbsp;
                                {{ $evento->dalle_alle }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $evento->Bezeichnung }}
                                @if($evento->Objekt != null) , luogo: {{ $evento->Objekt }} @endif
                                , {{ $evento->Einsatzart }}
                                @if($evento->Leiter != null) , responsabile: {{ $evento->Leiter }} @endif
                            </td>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione sm, md e lg -->
                            <td class="hidden-xs on-one-line">
                                {{ HTML::link('#annuncio_assenza', 'Annuncia', ['onclick' => 'specAgenda('.$evento->KeyAgenda.')', 'id' => 'form_assenza', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'name' => 'link_form_assenza', 'data-value' => $evento->KeyAgenda]) }}
                            </td>
                            <!-- Visualizzazione xs -->
                            <td class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg on-one-line">
                                {{ HTML::link('#annuncio_assenza', 'Ann.', ['onclick' => 'specAgenda('.$evento->KeyAgenda.')', 'id' => 'form_assenza', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'name' => 'link_form_assenza', 'data-value' => $evento->KeyAgenda]) }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ********** FINE PORTLET ********** -->
</div>
```

As you can imagine every event has a key, which I save in the data-value of my link ($evento->KeyAgenda).
Now, as the page does not reload how can I pass my key to my modal form?
I tried with some JavaScript but it doesn't seem to work and it's been to day wasted now, I'm sick.

Can someone help me making this work???
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean pass to modal form, you mean post it you just add it to post later?

Comment: Hi... I posted an answer which is in fact a reply to your question... I did it by mistake, this is my first post.

Comment: please push your code on github

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain better the situation...

I have the view with the calendar. I populate the table using a foreach and data from a model.
See the image at this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ewcmy73gksjwcw/calendario.jpg?dl=0

Then I have my modal form, which is linked to the word "Annuncia" on the last column, like that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjft7a1wtb6wvj2/modaleassenza.jpg?dl=0

What I'd like to do is to populate the form with some information which are connected to the row event. For example when I click on the first raw the modal should have the bold parts already filled with the right records (description, date and time).

I hope it's clearer now... and sorry but English is not my mother language.